# " ... a place where they can go ... " vs. " ... a place where to go ... "

Tags: difference, phrase-usage, verbs, infinitives

> Language changes, as everything does. Doubly important, then, that these members have their club. “This is a full-time job for me, but I don’t mind,” Mr. Allen said. “I see these people get satisfaction, ***a place where to go and where to meet***. They sit down and talk to each other.”

I have read a lot of pieces on The New York Times where, as [in the quote above](http://www.nytimes.com/2001/06/28/garden/three-stories-tall-and-a-hundred-deep.html?pagewanted=all&src=pm), the phrase “a place where” is followed by/from an infinitive. So I presume this structure is “idiomatic” English. Nevertheless, I’m under the impression that it is better to use “can” in these case. So, in reference to the above piece, we could say:

> Language changes, as everything does. Doubly important, then, that these members have their club. “This is a full-time job for me, but I don’t mind,” Mr. Allen said. “I see these people get satisfaction, ***a place where they can go and where they can meet***. They sit down and talk to each other.”

Can anybody explain what the difference is between these constructions?

Comment: I like your second construction better with _can_, a simpler way of phrasing it would be "_a place to go and meet_". I don't have an explanation though, so I don't have an answer to post.

Comment: It's not idiomatic. I note that the speaker is not a native English speaker, but an immigrant from Hungary, two of whose sons still speak Hungarian (albeit 'with an accent'), and that he is president of a social club for Hungarian immigrants; so it appears that he still maintains his mother tongue. Perhaps a Magyar-speaking user could tell us what the idiom would be in that language?

Comment: @Stoney, I don't know Hungarian, but Italians have no problem with both "un(a) posto(place) dove(where) andare(to go)" and "un(a) posto(place) dove(where) [they] poter(can) andare(go)".

Comment: ... although they are different in meaning.

Comment: I think maybe *a place where to go* is an Americanism. It seriously disturbs my delicate (British) ear. It's not the infinitive that bothers me - it's the excess word *where*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can assure you it's not a General Americanism, though for all I know it's current on the Upper East Side.

Comment: @StoneyB: Thank God for that! I was pretty taken aback earlier to see Google Books claiming 4510 instances of [a place where to go](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a+place+where+to+go%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). I should have had the courage of my convictions and gone on to Page:2 of the results - at which point I'd have discovered there are actually only 15 (and many seem to be from non-native speakers anyway). Perhaps it's actually just Too Localised. I certainly don't see why it should be of interest to the average *learner*.

Comment: @Fumble: It's of interest because it's just the kind of non-native-speaker error that English language learners make: they use structures & literally translated idioms from their native language when speaking English. It's typical when learning a new language to use the structure of your native language when speaking it. When I started to learn Chinese here in Taiwan, I consistently used Japanese syntax.

Comment: Hmm... this could indeed be a direct translation type of error. I'd render the bolded part as something like "...van helyük ahová mehetnek, ahol találkozhatnak...", which translates to "[there is] [their place] [to where] [they can go], [where] [they can meet]". And anecdotally, this does sound like something my mother would produce.

Answer (score 1):

I think that we may be missing some context.  It appears that this is a direct quote from a newspaper article or similar.  The person being quoted (as pointed out by @StoneyB) may not be a native English speaker, which may explain the unusual syntax.

If I were to rewrite the sentence for maximum clarity, I would write, "I see these people get satisfaction, a place to go and to meet. They sit down and talk to each other.”